# Expected type int got float in Pycharm

Tags: python-3.x, floating-point, int

```
    sub1=int(input("Enter the marks of the first subject: "))
    sub2=int(input("Enter the marks of the second subject: "))
    sub3=int(input("Enter the marks of the third subject: "))
    sub4=int(input("Enter the marks of the fourth subject: "))
    sub5=int(input("Enter the marks of the fifth subject: "))
    avg=(sub1+sub2+sub3+sub4+sub5)/5
    if(avg>=90):
      print("Grade A:")
    elif(avg>=80&avg<90):
      print("Grade B:")
    elif(avg>=70&avg<80):
      print("Grade C:")
    elif(avg>=60&avg<70):
      print("Grade D:")
    else:
      print("Grade F:")
```

Comment: Please read [ask]. You should post at least what you expect your code to do and what it actually does. Then actually ask a real question. Do not just post some code without extra information. Where did you expect an `int` and got a `float`? FWIW, you may want to read up on operators in https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#numeric-types-int-float-complex. You'll see that, in Python 3, `//` is the integer division operator, not `/`. Try `type(6/5)` and then `type(6//5)` on the Python command line to see what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `&` has higher precedence than the comparison operators (`>=`/`<`), so `avg>=80&avg<90` is being parsed as `avg>=(80&avg)<90`. It is then attempting to do [bitwise `&`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=bitwise#bitwise-operations-on-integer-types) between the two values, but failing.

You would be better writing it as either

```
avg>=70 and avg<80
```

([`and`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#and) is the short-circuiting operator, and has lower precedence), or

```
70 <= avg < 80
```